# Why does the first derivative of a piecewise continuous function have discontinuities?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, piecewise

I have this piecewise continuous function which is also continuously differentiable over time :

```
psi[t_] := Piecewise[{{(1 + t)^3 (-3 t^2 + t), -1 <= t <= 0},
                      {(1 - t)^3 (3 t^2 + t), 0 <= t <= 1}}];
```

Now, for starters, when I `Plot` it, a discontinuity appears. This can easily be solved with a simple `Exclusions -> None` option in the `Plot`command.

But then, when I calculate its first derivative over time using `D`, I obtain the following:

```
D[psi[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica session]

And then when I try to plot it :

[image: plot of the function]

- Is there something wrong with my original `psi[t_]`function? (Is it not continuous for *Mathematica*?)
- Why are the limits of definition of the first derivative modified?
- Why is the first derivative discontinuous?

Now, the *easy* solution would be to construct the first derivative using the results proposed by the `D` function and re-defining the definition domain... But I really want to understand this issue (if there is one).

Comment: Try `Plot[Evaluate[D[psi[t], t]], {t, -1, 1}]` or `Plot[D[psi[x], x] /. x -> t, {t, -1, 1}]`, or `Plot[D[psi[t], t], {t, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True]`.

Comment: Define $D[psi[t],t]$ to a funtion as $f[t _ ]=D[psi[t],t]$, then plot f[t]. It works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to define the derivative function:

```
dPsi[t_] = D[psi[t], t]
```

which can then be plotted:

```
Plot[dPsi[t], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The problem with your original formulation is that `D[psi[t],t]` does not evaluate to a function, it is instead d_t. The first derivative is not discontinuous, as a function, but it does have different definitions that correspond to the points where your `Piecewise` function changes.

Answer (score 8):

Somewhat surprisingly, the easiest solution seems to have been overlooked:

```
Plot[psi'[t], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

As `psi[t]` has already been defined, it makes sense to use `Derivative[]` for producing the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this with a little hack:

```
Plot[D[psi[x], x] /. x->t, {t,-3, 3}].
```

This way I force Mathematica to first find the derivative and then substitute t into x and evaluate. However, this calculates the derivative for every t, so for more complex functions, it may become a performance issue.

Comment: `Plot[D[psi[x], x], {x, -3, 3}, Evaluated -> True]` will give the same plot and avoid recalculating `D[psi[x], x]` :-)